# how to add shape in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to re-create the legend of zelda 1986 version in python and I immediately ran into a problem. I cant add the link gif to be the shape. Here is my code:

```
from turtle import*
screen=Screen()
link=Turtle()
walk="grid-cell-18443-1434401894-3.gif"
sword="legend-of-zelda-86.gif"
screen.addshape(walk)
screen.addshape(sword)
link.shape("walk")
```

I got an error. in short,

```
"_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "grid-cell-18443-1434401894-3.gif": 
no such file or directory"
```

It is a real file in the downloads folder! Please help!

And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your source code is running from a different location to where your images are stored.

If you move your images to your source code directory, you should not get the `no such file or directory` error.

You can check the current directory of your interpreter using functions from the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You can also change to the appropriate directory if you don't want to move the files.

```
os.chdir("/path/to/files")
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is where you did `walk="grid-cell-18443-1434401894-3.gif"` and then later using the string `walk` for turtle/tkinter. what you should do is either move  file "grid-cell-18443-1434401894-3.gif" to your python file, or do this code:

```
from turtle import*
screen=Screen()
link=Turtle()
walk="This PC/Downloads/grid-cell-18443-1434401894-3.gif"
sword="legend-of-zelda-86.gif"
screen.addshape(walk)
screen.addshape(sword)
link.shape("walk")
```